# Ubuntu 22.04, kernel version: 5.19.0-45-generic booting error

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

```
(20220331/nsinit-411)
0.2391571 ACPI Error: AE_TYPE, Could not execute arguments for [FRDO] (BufferF1eld) (20220331/nsinit-419)
0.239159] ACPI Error: AE_TYPE, Opcode is not deferred (FRD1] (BufferField)(20220331/nsinit-411)
[0.239160] API Error: AE_TYPE, Could not execute arguments for (FRD1] (Bufferfield)(20220331/nsinit-419)
0.2403501 ACPI Error: AE_TYPE, Opcode is not deferred (FRD0] (BufferField)(20220331/nsinit-411)
0.240352] ACPI Error: AE._TYPE, Could not execute arguments for IFRDO] (BufferField)(20220331/nsinit-419)
0.240354] ACPI Error: A_TYPE, Opcode is not deferred [FRD1] (BufferField)(20220331/nsinit-411)
0.240356] ACPI Error: A_TYPE, Could not execute arguments for (FRD11 (BufferField)(20220331/nsinit-419)
0.393484] pc 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size O is invalid
1.121047] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121073] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121096] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121119] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121142] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121165] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121191] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121217] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121240] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121263] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121287] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121310] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121333] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121356] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121380] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121403] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121427] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121453] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121475] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121498] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121521] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121543] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121569] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121594] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121617] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.121639] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.122581] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
1.264781] wmi: Failed to parse WDG method
/dev/nvme0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 227617/1222992 files, 3762147/4882432 blocks
2.304141] spi-nor spio.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: 20 43 19 20 43 19
2.304937] Serial bus multi instantiate pseudo device driver CSC3551:00: error -ENOENT: Error requesting irg at index 0: -2
```

Got this error while booting ubuntu, I tried to boot my windows and it worked just fine. Does anyone knows what is the problem? Read something about downgrading the kernel version. Sorry I’m still new to Ubuntu

Comment: does your Ubuntu boot and work fine, or does something else happen?

Comment: also did you use OCR or type this out yourself? because it has a bunch of typos/inconsistencies and doesn't look like it was copy-pasted

Comment: none of these errors look like they would cause your system to not work...

Comment: @Esther Hi thanks for your reply. I actually took a photo and copy paste them here. These lines of code appeared after GRUB menu, in which it will appear if I choose ubuntu. I tried running windows and it’s working just fine. Actually I’ve manage to get through it by logging in from recovery mode, but booting normally still get me stuck to that screen. Sometimes it can be a different line of code.

Comment: @Esther the thing is, it doesn’t happen everytime. Sometimes it stuck to that screen and sometimes it just loads. I’m really not sure what’s the main problem to be honest